# Question about finding volume of solids of revolution

Tags: calculus, integration

I stumbled upon a question that I'm stuck on. I'm not really sure how to approach this one:

[image]

Would I have to invert the $x$ and $y$?

Update: I got the answer $50.26548$ but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the question asks you to rotate the region over the y-axis. (i.e. the vertical axis) Integrate with respect to dy instead.

$\int_a^b f(y)~dy$

Comment: I did that and got ~ 50.2654 but that answer was wrong. Any other suggestions?

Comment: did you use the formula for rotation? pi*f(y)^2 - im getting a very nice and exact number

Comment: Yes I did, the radical and square cancel each other out so I should be left with A=pi*8*sin(y) right?

Comment: try using the symbolic notation they suggested, or try integrating with the bounds reversed, the range they gave you was a little weird

Comment: Would I have to use the washer method for this problem because I used the disc method to get my answer.

Comment: no, there's no hole - 16pi should be the correct answer

Comment: 16pi is the same as the answer that I tried (50.2654). Not sure why it's wrong..

Comment: are you sure that the system doesn't need an exact answer(i.e. 16pi) instead of an rounded number?

Comment: I double checked and tried 16pi as well but it still says i'm wrong somehow..